# Can no longer mount Guest Additions CD in Ubuntu VirtualBox guest

Tags: 13.10, mount, virtualbox, guest-additions

I've been using VirtualBox for weeks for school. Tonight, out of the blue, my virtual guest locks up and when I reset, there are so many issues.

I first had an issue with my screen no longer resizing as I drag the window - so I thought I would just resinstall Guest Additions. I ran the software manually (by opening the image and clicking "Run Software") and it appears to have done whatever it needed to. But the problem persists.

Now when I try to mount the Guest Additions image, I get the following error:

> **Unable to mount VBOXADDITIONS_4.3.6_91406** Error mounting /dev/sr0 at /media/user/VBOXADDITIONS_4.3.6_914061: Command-line mount-t "iso9660" -o [...] exited with
>   non-zero exit status 32: mount: unkown filesystem type 'iso9660'

Can someone *please* help me out? I'm a little desperate here... since I have projects due for class and can't really do anything efficiently now.

**Worth Noting:** I performed the same steps on a backup image I had of my VM, and the same issue is occurring. I have no idea what's changed...

Comment: provide the full path for your GuestAdditions.iso file.

Comment: Sorry about that; updated.